# Unity cant see sprites when changing them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 20 "Circle" objects on the scene and every one of them have the ObjectController script which needs to choose a random number between 1-3 and depends on what number it gets, change the sprite of the object. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer SR;

    private void Start()
    {
        SR = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(1, 4);
        switch (randomIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                ChangeSprite("obj_0003_Layer-4"); // Chest
                gameObject.AddComponent<ChestController>();
                break;
            case 2:
                ChangeSprite("obj_0020_Layer-21"); // Tree
                gameObject.AddComponent<TreeController>();
                break;
            case 3:
                ChangeSprite("obj_0028_Layer-29"); // Rock
                gameObject.AddComponent<RockController>();
                break;
        }

        gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().isTrigger = true;
    }

    private void ChangeSprite(string newSpriteName)
    {
        SR.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Graphics/BgAndThings/Objects/"
            + newSpriteName);
    }
}
```

I tried to check the pathway and add .png to the name of the image.

Edit: the AddComponent command in every case works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your import settings for the sprites? You should set the "Texture type" setting to the "Sprite (2D and UI)" -option.
Also you can try if you are the paths located wrong by having an array of sprites that you set directly. For example:

```
public Sprite[] sprites; // Set these in the inspector

case 1: SR.Sprite = Sprite[0]; break;
    
etc.
```

Comment: Banaani, it didn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried handling the UI elements as Image type instead of SpriteRenderer? Remember to include UnityEngine.UI